# What are mass constraints to mine the moon causing significant changes to orbital dynamics either tidal forces?

Tags: mining, risk-management

While US and EU governments seem now to give official [support](https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/a32082958/trump-moon-mining-asteroids/) for Moon mining, I wonder whether if we would mine away from the Moon same quantity we have mined on the Earth so far, would that introduce cosmological risk to Earth's conditions?

- mass of the Moon: 7.34767309 × 10<sup>22</sup> kg
- mined mass on the Earth so far to set a scale to what mass the humanity has been able to move around so far: could be [30 trillion tonnes](https://www.sciencealert.com/the-total-mass-of-earth-s-technosphere-is-30-trillion-tonnes) an upper limit?
- Moon mass extraction from where Earth's orbit either tidal forces would significantly change introducing terrestrial environmental risks: the answer to this question

In simpler words: ***would be there a problem with orbit dynamics/tidal forces if humanity mines 30 trillion tonnes off the Moon***? 
(Maybe, using self-replicating robotic mining complexes it could happen in decades or in a century).

Comment: I mean risks to Earth conditions, this is still very general but I think in a thought experiment mining the Moon completely away would be a problem. Now is there a lower limit where problems would start? would mining .001 percent of Moon mass introduce a risk to Earth?

Comment: Okay then I think it's a good idea if you make that crystal clear *in the question itself* since people sometimes vote to close long before they get to reading the comments.

Comment: J.Doe - suggest also constraining the question to orbital dynamics and possibly explicitly say the mass goes 'away'. Mining the moon and putting it on earth buries the surface pretty deep, mining the moon and using just the 'good stuff' on earth causes all sorts of waste problems. Moving the mass of the moon in human time scales involves more energy release than we can afford to have near earth. All of these give different results that I do not think answer your question and risk close votes

Comment: @GremlinWranger uhoh  - thank you for your feedback - now better?

Comment: 30 trillion tonnes, that is 3x10^16 kg. Compared to 7.34x10^22 kg it is only 0.4 parts per million.

Comment: @uhoh that would be good, depends on how much is trillion in the referenced article, 10^12 either 10^18. Still, the question remains whether it could change tidal forces (if less than climate change changes the sea level nobody would notice that possibly)

Comment: Not an answer since I'm not trusting the numbers but playing with game/toy universe sandbox suggests that even vanishing the entire moon does not change Earth's orbit that much, giving a degree or so of temperature change. Suggests removing a mere 30 trillion tonnes will not have particularly interesting effects.

Comment: @J. Doe - will the mass be transfered from the Moon (launched to space) or along the Moon?

Comment: @Heopps launched to outer space in form of iron and oxygen.

Comment: Recommend closing as idle speculation

Comment: Mining on the surface of the moon to change its orbit is like doing a slingshot maneuver around Jupiter to change Jupiter's orbit (it isn't feasible).

Comment: I think this is a perfectly reasonable question within Space Exploration SE.

Comment: I think this question has merit. I'm skeptical of the 30 trillion tonnes mined on Earth & what has been included in that number. One thing to remember, not everything that is mined is useful. To mine ore, some waste needs to be mined. The waste will not leave the Moon. Also, it is unlikely the minerals in the ore, as mined, will leave the Moon. They will either be concentrated or the metal extracted from them & that will leave the Moon. It won't be a case of dig stuff up & send it all off the Moon. Generally open pit mines extract more waste than ore.

Comment: How much mass of crew, equipment, and supplies needs to be sent to the moon to extract 30 teratons?

Comment: that number 30 teratonnes is just an upper limit for the thought experiment. Still I consider that self-replicating mining infrastructure can offer enough scale.